# ngFor with localStorage

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, ngfor

I got a problem with the ngFor, im doing ngFor for one array in order to create cards with images, the array contains the urls, but when i add a new url the card image show but when i reload the url is gone from the array

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let url of array">
```

and i got this to add the url in the array

```
this.array.push(url);
```

so i was told i need a localstorage so i wont loose the data so i did this

```
  test1=localStorage.setItem("arrayUrl", JSON.stringify(this.array));
  local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arrayUrl"));
```

after that i did this

```
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let url of local">
```

but its not working because images are not being displayed when adding to the array, so i have to add the url to the array or to the localstorage or where? and how do i manage to create thoose card images with the ngfor and make them permanently

Comment: where in your component are you doing this 
`test1=localStorage.setItem("arrayUrl", JSON.stringify(this.array));
  local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arrayUrl"));` ? 

Could you please show more of your relevant code sections?

Comment: Im doing that in the .ts file here is the res and thats the most important thing in the .ts file, because i have the method that only do

         this.array.push(url);

Comment: Yes, but where in the .ts file is the question. Is it inside any specific method or is that simply declared without being part of any method? Could you please show more of your component code?

Comment: question is that when doing the ngfor with the localstorage variable the image wont show, so i dont know where is the error

Comment: Well i wish i knew where you are getting the url from to begin with. Are you subscribing it from backend or some other outside apis? Regardless, if you want it in to stay in the browser, you need to save it in local storage. Just tell us where the url is from. Thanks

Comment: Is it just not displaying, or is it not being saved to local storage at all?  You can check it through the developer console (under Storage in Firefox, Application in Chrome, not sure about other browsers).

Comment: @JaimeCuellar Yes, I get that but in order to debug, it would be helpful how/where you are performing setting and getting on the localStorage. Without seeing the section (not just the line of code that does it, but the context as well, like which method/life-cycle-hook is it part of and such) it is hard to try and help.

Comment: I have a feeling this problem is due to pushing the url into the this.array. The url should not disappear if you have saved it in that global array variable (btw should be declared as an array). You need to push the url one at a time into the array from wherever you're getting from. Then if you want this array to be accessible when you reload the page, it needs to be in the constructor or in ngOnIn() method.

Comment: im getting the url from a text field and then calling the function when clicking on a button @EyoelD and im doing the localStorage inside the component class, not inside the method, i tried doing it inside the method after the .push but same error

Comment: If you are getting it from text field then why are you losing the data when your component page reloads? lets say you have [(ngModel)]="url" in your html data bined with your component.  First go and declare a variable array:Array<String>; and url:String; and make a method called arrayAdderButton(){ this.array.push(this.url); }. Now also call make a new method called loadArrayonDefault(){ return this.array }. Go to ngOnIn(){ this.loadArrayonDefault()}. Now your page loads with all the url everytime u reload this component. If this doesn't work, then posting your code might help us help you.